# How can I make a component render onClick in a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm a bit surprised I'm having trouble finding this online, but I can't seem to find an example of how to do this in a React functional component. I have a React component that I would like to render when I click a button. Right now the function fires and I can see my console.log firing, however the component isn't rendering. My first guess was that it won't render because React doesn't know to update the view, however I added boolean via useState and it still won't render. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the relevant code. How can I get the component in addSection to render?

```
const FormGroup = ({index}) => {
  const [additionalSection, setAdditionalSection] = useState(false);

  const addSection = form => {
    setAdditionalSection(true);
    console.log('form', form);

    return additionalSection && (
      <div key={form.prop}>
        <p>This should render</p>
        <AdditiveSection
          form={form}
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
  ...
 return (
...
 <FormAdd>
   <LinkButton
      type="button"
      onClick={() => addSection(form)}
   >
     span className="button--small">{form.button}</span>
   </LinkButton>
 </FormAdd>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A state change like the one you are calling, will trigger a re-render.

But all html to be rendered must be included in the functional components return statement.
The elements you want to render can be conditionally rendered like this:

```
    const FormGroup = ({index}) => {
      const [additionalSection, setAdditionalSection] = useState(false);
    
      const addSection = form => {
        setAdditionalSection(true);
        console.log('form', form);
      };
      ...
     return (
    ...
     <FormAdd>
       <LinkButton
          type="button"
          onClick={() => addSection(form)}
       >
         <span className="button--small">{form.button}</span>
       </LinkButton>
       {additionalSection && 
         <div key={form.prop}>
            <p>This should render</p>
            <AdditiveSection
              form={form}
              register={register}
              errors={errors}
            />
          </div>
       }
     </FormAdd>
    );
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure why this works. I have several functions in this component that return a function and render the html just fine. Thanks

Comment: If the function that returns HTML is called directly from the functional components return statement, the returned HTML will be rendered. I hope that explains the behavior you're seeing, otherwise I don't know

Answer (score 1):

You should change your state (or a prop in your useEffect dependency array in case you had one) in order to force a rerender. In this case:

setAdditionalSection(prevState=>!prevState);

Comment: I'm sorry your sentence doesn't make sense to me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What doesn't make sense exactly

Comment: You are forcing always your state to be true. You should toggle it to false/true if you want a rerender.

Comment: On click I'm adding a section so I always want it to be true if I clicked. In either case this doesn't solve my primary issue.

Comment: But what's the point of having a state with always the same value?

Comment: Do you know how to make my component render?

Comment: Of course adding another flag state Which you toggle to true false onClick would solve. But check well your code.

Comment: Your toggle doesn't solve my issue. And if my problem was setAdditionalSection(true) then it would work, but only the first time.