# How can I return a React Component from a function and render it onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that I am looping through in my higher order component. On click I want to pass one of those objects to my component and render that component. The problem I am having is it's unclear how to return the component and have React update the render to show that component. I've read several [Stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699541/how-can-i-make-a-component-render-onclick-in-a-react-functional-component/71699679?noredirect=1#comment126714720_71699679) on this and the problem of putting the component in the html is it passes all the items in my loop to my component instead of just the one I need onClick.

The warning I'm seeing in my console is `react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component />` Which makes sense however, I'm not sure what the proper syntax is to solve this problem. Below is the relevant code.

```
const FormGroup = ({index}) => {

  const renderSection = form => ( // I want to render this
    <AdditiveSection
      form={form}
      register={register}
      errors={errors}
    />
  );

   const addSection = form => {
     setAdditionalSection(prevState => !prevState);
     console.log('form', form);
     renderSection(form);
   };

  return (
    <section>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {myForm.controls.map(form => {
          if (form.type === 'section') {
            return (
              <FormSection>
                <div className="section__label">
                  <h4>{form.label}</h4>
                </div>

                ...

                {form.button
                && (
                <FormAdd>
                  <LinkButton
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => addSection(form)} // called here and passes my form object
                >
                  <span className="button--small">{form.button}</span>
                  </LinkButton>
                </FormAdd>
                )}

                {renderFormType(form)}
              </FormSection>
            );
          }

        })}

        // renderSection should render here outside of the loop
        {additionalSection && renderSection}


        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  </section>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else may be struggling with this. Thanks to szaman and this [article.](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/calling-a-react-component-on-button-click) Turns out I need to pass the section in the loop, but just pass through the data that was clicked.

```
 const addSection = form => {
   console.log('form', form);
   setAdditionalSection(form);
 };

return (
  <section>
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
    <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {myForm.controls.map(form => {
        if (form.type === 'section') {
          return (
            <FormSection>
              <div className="section__label">
                <h4>{form.label}</h4>
              </div>

              ...

              {form.button
              && (
              <FormAdd>
                <LinkButton
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => addSection(form)} // called here and passes my form object
              >
                  <span className="button--small">{form.button}</span>
                </LinkButton>
              </FormAdd>
             )}

              {additionalSection && additionalSection.position === ind && (
                <AdditiveSection
                  form={additionalSection}
                  register={register}
                  errors={errors}
                />
              )}

             {renderFormType(form)}
            </FormSection>
          );
        }

      })}


      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </FormProvider>
</section>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in state and just render.

```
const { extraSection, setExtraSection } = useState(null);

const addSection = form => {
  setExtraSection(form);
};

return (
  ...
  // renderSection should render here outside of the loop
  {extraSection}
);
```

The problem with your original approach is that you were not saving that element anywhere. You called `renderSection` upon click, but that just called the function without storing or displaying that code anywhere.

Then in you render method, you again referenced `rederSection`. This is just a copy of the function, now without a parameter. It doesn't have any element as parameter, and it's not even called, so React is complaining that you're trying to render a function, instead of an element.

Comment: In the example you provided here you are not rendering my component you are just rendering the state. I need to pass the form to my component. My component does more than just display what I'm passing it.

Comment: @London804 ? i omitted the other parts for simplicity (hence the `...` placeholder). simply insert it in the appropriate places in your code, replacing your methods and the part where you render the form.

Answer (score 0):

**try it**

```
const renderSection = form => (
    
return(      
   <AdditiveSection       
       form={form}       
       register={register}       
       errors={errors}        
   />
  )
);
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but this is the same thing as what I created except yours has an explicit return.